# Only send messages to Discord without polling(not webhook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I need to split the message logic and put incoming messages into a message queue before taking them out and running them. But the message queue requires the object to be json serialisable. So I can only pass parameters and rebuild the bot object on another machine.

But it seems many discord python sdk can't work **without polling**.

In my vision.
It should have an API like this:

```
client(bot_token)
await client.create_message(
            1153xxxxxxxxxxx49, f "message here"!
        )
```

but it not.

How can I build a message and send it with just parameters and a bot Token?

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#identify

Comment: Can't you just create a channel from the channel's ID, then send the message to that channel?

Comment: No...asyn polling blocks the program directly,i must wait the event arrived

Comment: i dont need polling,it will ruin everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some research,finally found some Solution:

RestAPP
https://github.com/hikari-py/hikari#rest-only-applications

HttpClient
https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/pull/1057